# Get the smallest difference of all possible element combinations in an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, optimization, difference

I have a very, very long array and I have to get the minimum difference of all possible combinations of 2 elements.

This is my code:

```
[...]
int diff = 1000000; // a very big difference that i'm sure is too big
int tmpDiff; // swap
//Compare
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {    // I try every combination of 2 elements of array
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {  // don't repeat same elements
        tmpDiff = abs(array[i] - array[j]); // get the difference
        if (diff > tmpDiff) { // if it is smaller is the difference i need
            diff = tmpDiff;
        }

    }
}
[...]
```

It takes too much time. How could we optimize performances?

Comment: Use an efficient sort, then go through the list sequentially comparing  adjacent elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array first. Then you only need to compare consecutive values. And you don't even need to use `abs()` as you know which of the two elements it the bigger one.

If the array must not be changed, copy it first (not shown below).

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// compare function for integer, compatible with qsort
int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    return *ia  - *ib; 
} 

...

int diff = INT_MAX;
int d;

// sort
qsort(array, N, sizeof(array[0]), int_cmp);

// compare consecutive elements
for (size_t i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    d = array[i] - array[i - 1];
    if (d < diff)
        diff = d;
}
```

**Update**

`qsort` sorts an array using the *Quicksort* algorithm. The cost of the sorting is of the order O(n ln n) as opposed to O(n^2) if you have two nested *for* loops. For bigger arrays (n > 100), this can make a huge difference. Just do the math: approx. 500 vs. 10,000.

The comparison function passed to `qsort` is always tricky as `qsort` is written such that it works with arrays of any type. The function is passed the address of (pointer to) two elements in the array. For small types such as integer, it would be handy if it passed the integers directly. But instead, you have to deal with the address. So what you do is two things:

1. Convert the pointer to a more specific type, i.e. from a pointer of any type (`void*`) to a pointer to an integer (`int*`).
2. Dereference the pointer, i.e. get the effective value by using the `*` operator, in this case `*ia` and `*ib`.

The functions needs to return a number less than 0 if the first integer is smaller than the second one, 0 if they are equal and a number greater than 0 if the second number is bigger. So an old trick comes in handy: just return the difference between the first and second number.

Comment: Perfect, it works ;) Could you link me a simply explanation about qsort and how the comparing function must be written? Because at university we didn't yet studied pointers and function pointers (but doesn't matter, I want to know :P). I found only complicated explanations XD

Comment: Going from a O(N^2) to a average O(N log N) should be a huge improvement. Unless you hit the worst case for quicksort.

Comment: I've added a description of the comparison function.